# Do fractals contain solutions for problems?

Tags: fractals, np-complete

I notice that fractals resemble natural shapes such as leaves or rivers. Leaves and rivers are solutions to problems in themselves. A leaf is trying to distribute the water to the leaf while the leaf may become broken and the leaf needs to distribute the water efficiently. So this leads me to think, is a fractal a solution to a problem just as a leaf is a solution to a problem?

Are there solutions to math problems hidden in fractals?

Are there solutions to real world problems in fractals?

If so, do fractals provide any solutions to hard problems which would be difficult to solve otherwise? Any quick ways to solve problems with fractals?

*Added comments*

I still think there is some potential to find solutions to problems within fractals, although no answer on this issue.

Comment: Rather too soft a question for me, but at least in the case of lungs, the fractal arrangement allows for maximal surface area for absorbing oxygen within a very confined space.

Comment: *Some* fractals resemble leaves or rivers, some (most!) fractals don't resemble anything anyone but a mathematician has ever seen, or will ever see.

Comment: I think you should read Mandelbrot's book *The Fractal Geometry of Nature*.  That's his thesis: that everything in the world (practically) is a fractal, and why.

Comment: The real world rarely covers more than a decade in scale, so self-similar mappings can be done over only a limited range of scales.  An exception might be turbulence or phase transitions.  @Phil Maybe that's the kind of problem that you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this question is a little too vague. Put simply, yes, but it depends upon both the problem and the fractal. Yes because there are some examples, so that is enough to draw a conclusion for how you asked the question. The second question is also yes for the same reason, and your leaf example as well as a comment's lungs example prove both questions. The third question, "Any quick ways to solve problems with fractals?" is the hard one. I would say that surface area questions would probably be what you are looking for, and there are ways to solve these with simple fractals, so, yes again? Again, I advise making this question more strict for better information.